# Чтение двух чисел из файла и вывод их суммы в другой файл на Python!

Tags: python

> Даны два числа A и B. Вам нужно вычислить их сумму A+B. В этой задаче вам нужно читать из файла и выводить ответ в файл
>
> Формат ввода
> Первая строка входного файла содержит числа A и B (-2 ⋅ 109 ≤ A, B ≤ 2 ⋅ 109) разделенные пробелом
>
> Формат вывода
> В единственной строке выходного файла выведите сумму чисел A+B

Comment: Покажите Вашу попытку решения подскажем, поправим. Выполнять задание за Вас никто не будет.

Answer (score 1):

1. Считайте строку в файле с помощью:
   https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open
2. Разделите строку по символу пробела
   https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split
3. Получите сумму объектов получившегося пунктом 2 списка
4. Сохраните сумму в файл с помощью open() из пункта 1